# Web scraping a table from dynamic website (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am fairly new to web scraping and decided to dive straight into the deep end. I want select any product and "all months" in a dropdown above the table from https://www.cmegroup.com/tools-information/quikstrike/options-calendar.html and extract the table data into a scv file. The problem araises because the website is dynamic (not all HTML code is displayed when clicking inspect sourse in browser) and generates the table in css (from what i managed to understand). I tried using Selenium to load the webpage, but I am getting an error.

[12508:8412:0216/220631.827:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(985)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101

I am assuming this has to do with the webdriver initialisation and I need to give it some settings, just not sure which ones.

Here is the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Set up the Selenium driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open the webpage
url = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/tools-information/quikstrike/options-calendar.html'
driver.get(url)

# Render the page and extract the HTML code
html = driver.page_source

# Parse the HTML using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Extract the data you want from the soup object
tables = soup.findAll("table")

print(tables)

# Close the Selenium driver
driver.quit()
```

I have tried going the short route and reproducing the requests made by the browser and catching the response with the HTML code (yes the request only returns HTML, not JSON), but this backfired as I couldnt reproduce payload. How do I get the data from the calendar?

Comment: _I want select a product and "all months" in a table_: What are the manual steps to repro the issue?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Not sure what you mean by the first comment, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<table>` element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so to access/print the *`<table>`* contents you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the *visibility_of_element_located*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.cmegroup.com/tools-information/quikstrike/options-calendar.html')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='cmeIframe']")))
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ui-widget-info clearfix']/table//tbody[not(@class)][.//tr[@class='group compact']]"))).text)
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  FEBRUARY 2023
  FIRST AVAIL DATE OPTION EXPIRATION DTE PRODUCT OPTION FUTURE FUTURE EXPIRATION DTE
  20 Jan 2023 - Fri 17 Feb 2023 - Fri 1 Natural Gas Weekly Financial Option Week 3 LN3G3 NGH3 24 Feb 2023 - Fri 8
  24 Nov 2010 - Wed 23 Feb 2023 - Thu 7 Natural Gas Option (European) LNEH3 NGH3 24 Feb 2023 - Fri 8
  27 Jan 2023 - Fri 24 Feb 2023 - Fri 8 Natural Gas Weekly Financial Option Week 4 LN4G3 NGJ3 29 Mar 2023 - Wed 41
  MARCH 2023
  FIRST AVAIL DATE OPTION EXPIRATION DTE PRODUCT OPTION FUTURE FUTURE EXPIRATION DTE
  03 Feb 2023 - Fri 03 Mar 2023 - Fri 15 Natural Gas Weekly Financial Option Week 1 LN1H3 NGJ3 29 Mar 2023 - Wed 41
  10 Feb 2023 - Fri 10 Mar 2023 - Fri 22 Natural Gas Weekly Financial Option Week 2 LN2H3 NGJ3 29 Mar 2023 - Wed 41
  21 Feb 2023 - Tue 17 Mar 2023 - Fri 29 Natural Gas Weekly Financial Option Week 3 LN3H3 NGJ3 29 Mar 2023 - Wed 41
  27 Feb 2023 - Mon 24 Mar 2023 - Fri 36 Natural Gas Weekly Financial Option Week 4 LN4H3 NGJ3 29 Mar 2023 - Wed 41
  24 Nov 2010 - Wed 28 Mar 2023 - Tue 40 Natural Gas Option (European) LNEJ3 NGJ3 29 Mar 2023 - Wed 41
  06 Mar 2023 - Mon 31 Mar 2023 - Fri 43 Natural Gas Weekly Financial Option Week 5 LN5H3 NGK3 26 Apr 2023 - Wed 69
  APRIL 2023
  FIRST AVAIL DATE OPTION EXPIRATION DTE PRODUCT OPTION FUTURE FUTURE EXPIRATION DTE
  13 Mar 2023 - Mon 06 Apr 2023 - Thu 49 Natural Gas Weekly Financial Option Week 1 LN1J3 NGK3 26 Apr 2023 - Wed 69
  20 Mar 2023 - Mon 14 Apr 2023 - Fri 57 Natural Gas Weekly Financial Option Week 2 LN2J3 NGK3 26 Apr 2023 - Wed 69
  27 Mar 2023 - Mon 21 Apr 2023 - Fri 64 Natural Gas Weekly Financial Option Week 3 LN3J3 NGK3 26 Apr 2023 - Wed 69
  24 Nov 2010 - Wed 25 Apr 2023 - Tue 68 Natural Gas Option (European) LNEK3 NGK3 26 Apr 2023 - Wed 69
  03 Apr 2023 - Mon 28 Apr 2023 - Fri 71 Natural Gas Weekly Financial Option Week 4 LN4J3 NGM3 26 May 2023 - Fri 99
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)